# Is there now a brief grace period between when a question goes on hold and when answers to it are blocked?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bug

After completing an answer to the question ['compare [something] with/to [something]' vs. 'compare'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/299667/compare-something-with-to-something-vs-compare), I clicked 'Post Your Answer' and the answer went live. But unbeknownst to me, a moderator had put the question on hold almost 10 minutes earlier.

How did my answer get through? Is there now a grace period of, say, 10 or 15 minutes to allow people who were in the midst of writing an answer to post it after the question is put on hold? Or was my answer saved by a glitch in the automated process of answer blocking?

I would be delighted if there were some sort of 10- or 15-minute warning on questions that are about to go on hold, so that answerers would know either to abandon ship or to get their initial version of an answer in before the wall goes up. But perhaps, from EL&U's perspective, the block needs to appear without warning in order to prevent people from posting answers (or the skeletal beginnings of answers) to questions whose value is in question.

Comment: Yes, it appears that there is, and it's infuriating from a moderation point of view (although I know first-hand that it's infuriating to have an "answers are no longer accepted for this question" message, too).

Comment: I could swear that I've tried to post answers within one hour of their being closed and haven't succeeded. But I don't remember much about the details surrounding those instances—only that I was surprised to see that the question had been closed, and disappointed that my answer wasn't going to stick. Still, the question that Mitch points to in his comment above sounds identical to the one I just asked, so I guess I should click the "That solved my problem!" button.